# WSO2 server does not start with imported package in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, wso2

I have created a plugin jar for a custom authentication with wso2. I have to use an external jar which I get from a nexus repository. 
Then in my pom.xml I have this

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Private-Package>
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.raiff.extension.auth.internal,
                    </Private-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.osgi.framework; version="${osgi.framework.imp.pkg.version.range}",
                        org.osgi.service.component; version="${osgi.service.component.imp.pkg.version.range}",
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.base; version="${carbon.identity.framework.version.range}",
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.*; version="${carbon.identity.framework.version.range}",
                        org.apache.commons.logging; version="${version.commons.logging}",
                        org.apache.commons.lang; version="${commons.lang.version}",
                        javax.servlet.http.*; version="${sevlet.api.version}",
                        javax.naming.ldap,
                        javax.naming.directory,
                        javax.security.auth.x500,
                        javax.naming,
                        org.apache.commons.codec.binary,
                        org.apache.xml.security.utils,
                        org.wso2.carbon.base,
                        org.wso2.carbon.user.core.*,
                        org.wso2.carbon.user.api,
                        org.wso2.carbon.core.util,
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.*;version="${carbon.identity.framework.version.range}",
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model;version="${carbon.identity.framework.version.range}",
                        com.hpes.aeon.repo.metadata.v1.0
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        !org.wso2.carbon.identity.raiff.extension.auth.internal,
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.raiff.extension.auth.*,
                    </Export-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>
                        *;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false;artifactId=com.hpes.aeon.repo.metadata.v1.0
                    </Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But when I make mvn clean install and copy the jar into ...\repository\components\dropins and start the wso2server.bat it doesn't load my two custom authenticators.

I am sure it is related to the pom because when I remove my external jar that I have included above

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.mygroup.xy</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
        <version>java8.20191209140725</version>
    </dependency>
```

and also com.hpes.aeon.repo.metadata.v1.0 inside the Import-Package, it works. I have read that inside Embed-Dependency one could add his own package, but it doesn't change at all.

Thank you.

Comment: I have now removed the <Embed-Dependency> part and also com.hpes.aeon.repo.metadata.v1.0, it compiles, but when I start the wso2server it says NoClassDefFoundError Exception for one of the class of com.hpes.aeon.repo.metadata

Comment: Try adding the dependency jar to `...\repository\components\lib\`. And keep the import line.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the import com.hpes.aeon.repo.metadata.v1.0.
Check and use the correct package name and version to import

Comment: You can try to osgi console debug to narrow down the issue, Follow this for more info https://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-debug-wso2-carbon-products-using.html